# make service unkilled even when app clossed

Tags: android, service

I m working  pedometer app  and i have one service class which extends service  class .

```
   public class StepService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG =  "name.bagi.levente.pedometer.StepService";
private SharedPreferences mSettings;
private PedometerSettings mPedometerSettings;
private SharedPreferences mState;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mStateEditor;
private Utils mUtils;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
private StepDetector mStepDetector;
// private StepBuzzer mStepBuzzer; // used for debugging
private StepDisplayer mStepDisplayer;
private PaceNotifier mPaceNotifier;
private DistanceNotifier mDistanceNotifier;
private SpeedNotifier mSpeedNotifier;
private CaloriesNotifier mCaloriesNotifier;
private SpeakingTimer mSpeakingTimer;

private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
private NotificationManager mNM;

private int mSteps;
private int mPace;
private float mDistance;
private float mSpeed;
private float mCalories;

/**
 * Class for clients to access.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with
 * IPC.
 */
public class StepBinder extends Binder {
    StepService getService() {
        return StepService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  //  Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] onCreate");
    super.onCreate();

    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    showNotification();

    // Load settings
    mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mPedometerSettings = new PedometerSettings(mSettings);
    mState = getSharedPreferences("state", 0);

    mUtils = Utils.getInstance();
    mUtils.setService(this);
    mUtils.initTTS();

    acquireWakeLock();

    // Start detecting
    mStepDetector = new StepDetector();
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    registerDetector();

    // Register our receiver for the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF action. This will make our receiver
    // code be called whenever the phone enters standby mode.
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    mStepDisplayer = new StepDisplayer(mPedometerSettings, mUtils);
    mStepDisplayer.setSteps(mSteps = mState.getInt("steps", 0));
    mStepDisplayer.addListener(mStepListener);
    mStepDetector.addStepListener(mStepDisplayer);

    mPaceNotifier     = new PaceNotifier(mPedometerSettings, mUtils);
    mPaceNotifier.setPace(mPace = mState.getInt("pace", 0));
    mPaceNotifier.addListener(mPaceListener);
    mStepDetector.addStepListener(mPaceNotifier);

    mDistanceNotifier = new DistanceNotifier(mDistanceListener, mPedometerSettings, mUtils);
    mDistanceNotifier.setDistance(mDistance = mState.getFloat("distance", 0));
    mStepDetector.addStepListener(mDistanceNotifier);

    mSpeedNotifier    = new SpeedNotifier(mSpeedListener,    mPedometerSettings, mUtils);
    mSpeedNotifier.setSpeed(mSpeed = mState.getFloat("speed", 0));
    mPaceNotifier.addListener(mSpeedNotifier);

    mCaloriesNotifier = new CaloriesNotifier(mCaloriesListener, mPedometerSettings, mUtils);
    mCaloriesNotifier.setCalories(mCalories = mState.getFloat("calories", 0));
    mStepDetector.addStepListener(mCaloriesNotifier);

    mSpeakingTimer = new SpeakingTimer(mPedometerSettings, mUtils);
    mSpeakingTimer.addListener(mStepDisplayer);
    mSpeakingTimer.addListener(mPaceNotifier);
    mSpeakingTimer.addListener(mDistanceNotifier);
    mSpeakingTimer.addListener(mSpeedNotifier);
    mSpeakingTimer.addListener(mCaloriesNotifier);
    mStepDetector.addStepListener(mSpeakingTimer);

    // Used when debugging:
    // mStepBuzzer = new StepBuzzer(this);
    // mStepDetector.addStepListener(mStepBuzzer);

    // Start voice
    reloadSettings();

    // Tell the user we started.
    Toast.makeText(this, getText(R.string.started), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
   // Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] onStart");
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  //  Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] onDestroy");
    mUtils.shutdownTTS();

    // Unregister our receiver.
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    unregisterDetector();

    mStateEditor = mState.edit();
    mStateEditor.putInt("steps", mSteps);
    mStateEditor.putInt("pace", mPace);
    mStateEditor.putFloat("distance", mDistance);
    mStateEditor.putFloat("speed", mSpeed);
    mStateEditor.putFloat("calories", mCalories);
    mStateEditor.commit();

    mNM.cancel(R.string.app_name);

    wakeLock.release();

    super.onDestroy();

    // Stop detecting
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mStepDetector);

    // Tell the user we stopped.
    Toast.makeText(this, getText(R.string.stopped), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void registerDetector() {
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
        Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER /*| 
        Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD | 
        Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION*/);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mStepDetector,
        mSensor,
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}

private void unregisterDetector() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mStepDetector);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
 //   Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] onBind");
    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * Receives messages from activity.
 */
private final IBinder mBinder = new StepBinder();

public interface ICallback {
    public void stepsChanged(int value);
    public void paceChanged(int value);
    public void distanceChanged(float value);
    public void speedChanged(float value);
    public void caloriesChanged(float value);
}

private ICallback mCallback;

public void registerCallback(ICallback cb) {
    mCallback = cb;
    //mStepDisplayer.passValue();
    //mPaceListener.passValue();
}

private int mDesiredPace;
private float mDesiredSpeed;

/**
 * Called by activity to pass the desired pace value, 
 * whenever it is modified by the user.
 * @param desiredPace
 */
public void setDesiredPace(int desiredPace) {
    mDesiredPace = desiredPace;
    if (mPaceNotifier != null) {
        mPaceNotifier.setDesiredPace(mDesiredPace);
    }
}
/**
 * Called by activity to pass the desired speed value, 
 * whenever it is modified by the user.
 * @param desiredSpeed
 */
public void setDesiredSpeed(float desiredSpeed) {
    mDesiredSpeed = desiredSpeed;
    if (mSpeedNotifier != null) {
        mSpeedNotifier.setDesiredSpeed(mDesiredSpeed);
    }
}

public void reloadSettings() {
    mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if (mStepDetector != null) { 
        mStepDetector.setSensitivity(
                Float.valueOf(mSettings.getString("sensitivity", "10"))
        );
    }

    if (mStepDisplayer    != null) mStepDisplayer.reloadSettings();
    if (mPaceNotifier     != null) mPaceNotifier.reloadSettings();
    if (mDistanceNotifier != null) mDistanceNotifier.reloadSettings();
    if (mSpeedNotifier    != null) mSpeedNotifier.reloadSettings();
    if (mCaloriesNotifier != null) mCaloriesNotifier.reloadSettings();
    if (mSpeakingTimer    != null) mSpeakingTimer.reloadSettings();
}

public void resetValues() {
    mStepDisplayer.setSteps(0);
    mPaceNotifier.setPace(0);
    mDistanceNotifier.setDistance(0);
    mSpeedNotifier.setSpeed(0);
    mCaloriesNotifier.setCalories(0);
}

/**
 * Forwards pace values from PaceNotifier to the activity. 
 */
private StepDisplayer.Listener mStepListener = new StepDisplayer.Listener() {
    public void stepsChanged(int value) {
        mSteps = value;
        passValue();
    }
    public void passValue() {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.stepsChanged(mSteps);
        }
    }
};
/**
 * Forwards pace values from PaceNotifier to the activity. 
 */
private PaceNotifier.Listener mPaceListener = new PaceNotifier.Listener() {
    public void paceChanged(int value) {
        mPace = value;
        passValue();
    }
    public void passValue() {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.paceChanged(mPace);
        }
    }
};
/**
 * Forwards distance values from DistanceNotifier to the activity. 
 */
private DistanceNotifier.Listener mDistanceListener = new DistanceNotifier.Listener() {
    public void valueChanged(float value) {
        mDistance = value;
        passValue();
    }
    public void passValue() {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.distanceChanged(mDistance);
        }
    }
};
/**
 * Forwards speed values from SpeedNotifier to the activity. 
 */
private SpeedNotifier.Listener mSpeedListener = new SpeedNotifier.Listener() {
    public void valueChanged(float value) {
        mSpeed = value;
        passValue();
    }
    public void passValue() {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.speedChanged(mSpeed);
        }
    }
};
/**
 * Forwards calories values from CaloriesNotifier to the activity. 
 */
private CaloriesNotifier.Listener mCaloriesListener = new CaloriesNotifier.Listener() {
    public void valueChanged(float value) {
        mCalories = value;
        passValue();
    }
    public void passValue() {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.caloriesChanged(mCalories);
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Show a notification while this service is running.
 */
private void showNotification() {
    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.app_name);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_notification, null,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    Intent pedometerIntent = new Intent();
    pedometerIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, Pedometer.class));
    pedometerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            pedometerIntent, 0);
   /* notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, text,
            getText(R.string.notification_subtitle), contentIntent);

    mNM.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);*/
}


// BroadcastReceiver for handling ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Check action just to be on the safe side.
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // Unregisters the listener and registers it again.
            StepService.this.unregisterDetector();
            StepService.this.registerDetector();
            if (mPedometerSettings.wakeAggressively()) {
                wakeLock.release();
                acquireWakeLock();
            }
        }
    }
};

private void acquireWakeLock() {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    int wakeFlags;
    if (mPedometerSettings.wakeAggressively()) {
        wakeFlags = PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP;
    }
    else if (mPedometerSettings.keepScreenOn()) {
        wakeFlags = PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK;
    }
    else {
        wakeFlags = PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK;
    }
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(wakeFlags, TAG);
    wakeLock.acquire();
}
```

}

> ho to make this service live even when app killed also I have to count footstep even when app killed.
>   I m calling service like this.

```
   startService(new Intent(Pedometer.this,
                StepService.class));
```

Comment: Foreground service: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: What does "app killed" really mean? When the user forces the app to stop (for example via settings - apps) the service doesn't (and shouldn't) run any more.

Comment: Don't bind your service with the activity which you are using to start the service, then the service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed.

Comment: APP KILLED MEANS KILL FROM  CLOSED THE APP  COMPLEATLY

Comment: i have to display foot step which i am getting from service class

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
    {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        startStepService();
    }

    private void startStepService()
    {
        startService(new Intent(this,StepService.class));
    }
```